# Pythonw not responding

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4

I tried to learn make Gui with python using PyQt4 module, but when I run the program its gives error pythonw.exe is not responding. I am running python on windows 10.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
```

This error comes when I rn the program

[image]

Comment: add `sys.exit(app.exec_())`. Have you tried running it from the cmd?

Comment: No, I am running directly from Python shell.

Comment: Thank you eyllan, now it is running.

Comment: will you please briefly explain why did this happen?

Comment: PyQt create an internal loop, and this can block other tasks performed by the python shell